# How to run Mathematica using Mac Terminal

Tags: programming

My question is so trivial and I'm sure most people in here know exactly how to do this, however I still don't know how to run Mathematica in Mac terminal!

I need to use all the cores of my computer in order to get faster results. I open Mathematica in terminal using this command:

```
/Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/MacOS/MathKernel
```

Then when I type `math -run "<<test.m"` (test is my file's name), nothing happens! Can anybody guide me what to do or refer me to a good refrence with some examples at this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a test.m file content of :

```
Print["Hello World"];
```

At the kernel:

```
In[1]:=<<"test.m"                
Hello World

In[2]:=
```

Or, as an alternative run the file as a script

```
./MathKernel -script test.m
```