# Completion in terminal?

Tags: programming, autocomplete, command-line

I know that it is possible to [run Mathematica in Terminal](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/24143/how-to-run-mathematica-using-mac-terminal). But I didn't find a way to get completion work in Terminal. I mean `completion` by `bash-completion` style work, who auto completes a command with `TAB`. How to do this?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: An autocomplete in the command line would be a huge improvement in Mathematica, especially for ssh connections.

Answer (score 3):

I don't quite have full completion, but I do wrap Mathematica in GNU `rlwrap`. I know that you can teach `rlwrap` a list of keywords to autocomplete, and even program it to determine what completions to suggest from your context. At the very least, you get history and line editing out of it.

My recipe:

- I used MacPorts to install `rlwrap`, and their port seems to work fine.
- Create a list of Mathematica definitions that you care about and put it in `~/mathdefs.txt`.
- Then I added `alias math='rlwrap -r -f ~/mathdefs.txt /Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/MacOS/MathKernel'` to my login script.

  - The `-r` tells it to remember words that it sees you type during a session, and the `-f ~/mathdefs.txt` seeds its completion support with the words that you put in that file.

I notice that Wolfram has added their own history/editing support (probably using readline) in 10.1 at least. Quite possibly before then. I'm sure it wasn't there in 8.0, and I don't think it was in 9.0, but I'm not positive.

Comment: I found a list of definitions [here](https://github.com/oxinabox/Mathematica-Commandline-Interface). But how to make it autocomplete? Which key? `TAB` doesn't seem to work.