# Is there a way to omit the "In[1]:=" prompt?

Tags: interface, command-line

I'm using a command-line interface of Mathematica, or `/usr/bin/wolfram`. In wrapping this cui program with GNU Readline library, I would like to omit the `In[n] :=` prompt. In other words, I'd like to change

```
~ $ /usr/bin/wolfram
Wolfram Language 11.3.0 Engine for Linux ARM (32-bit)
Copyright 1988-2018 Wolfram Research, Inc.

In[1]:= 3 + 5                                                                                           

Out[1]= 8

In[2]:= f[x_] := x^
```

to

```
~ $ /usr/bin/wolfram
Wolfram Language 11.3.0 Engine for Linux ARM (32-bit)
Copyright 1988-2018 Wolfram Research, Inc.

3 + 5                                                                                           

Out[1]= 8

f[x_] := x^
```

Is there any options which omit or change the prompt?

---

Supplement:

`-noprompt` command line option gives this.

```
~ $ /usr/bin/wolfram -noprompt
3 + 5                                                                                           
8
f[x_] := x^
```

This also omits the `Out[n]=` prompt and a blank line, both of which I don't want to remove. (If these can be shown in some way, the `-noprompt` options is enough for me.)

---

Finally, thanks to the really great help of [Somos' answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/200833/66236), I came true what I wanted to do by writing the code below to the configuration file `~/.WolframEngine/Kernel/init.m`.

```
ST[] :=
Module[
    {input},
    Print[];
    While[True,
        input = InputString[""];
        If[input == EndOfFile, Quit[]];
        If[input == "", Continue[]];
        Print[];
        Print["Out[", ++$Line, "]= ", ToExpression[input]];
        Print[]
    ]       
]
```

What I get now:
[image]

By combining `wolfram` command and [GNU Readline Library](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html), you can equip mathematica with a highly functional line editor. As shown in the gif file above,

- completion of words
- highlighting an opening bracket when the corresponding closing bracket is typed
- rapid cursor movement not only to line's head or tail but also to any position like "next word" or "next occurrence of an alphabet Z".
- partly editing a line (e.g. delete next two words from the current position, or delete from this opening bracket to the corresponding closing bracket)
- history search (not shown in the gif)
- etc.

are realized **with custom key-binding which you like** (e.g. I'm using `wolfram` command with `vim`-like keybindings).

(`rlwrap` suggested in [MATHEMATICA - Completion in terminal?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/80773/completion-in-terminal) doesn't work well with recent `wolfram` command. Also [JMath: A GNU Readline based frontend for Mathematica](http://robotics.caltech.edu/~radford/jmath/) is out-dated. What I did is similar to [Mathematica with a GNU readline input (Python recipe)](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/363500-mathematica-with-a-gnu-readline-input/), though I write a longer C++ code to explicitly use Readline library and turn on additional functionality like completion.)

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "wrapping this cui program with GNU Readline library"?

Comment: "wrap" is a general word (at least in linux community I reside in) that means "to program a functional or user-friendly interface for some hard-to-use or too-complicated program". In my case, by using GNU Readline library, I wanted to compensate the non-sophisticated line editing functionality of `wolfram` command.

Comment: And you plan to do this with the "rlwrap" program perhaps? Or some other way to get Mathematica to use "readline"?

Comment: @Somos No. There is no "plan" any more. Thanks to your help, I succeeded in using Readline with mathematica. (Actually `In[] :=` prompt interferes with Readline, so I wanted to omit this to make my program more useful.)

Comment: Surprising to me, I just discovered that the Mathematica CLI that I was using already has "readline" editing and history, but no tab completion. How strange.

Comment: Really? What version of mathematica are you using? Mine is 11.3.0 on RaspberryPi platform (Linux platform). It is not strange you cannot use tab completion because what Readline can do is just to supply completion functionality itself. Completion candidate list (so-called "dictionary") must be prepared case by case by the programmer (in your case by Wolfram Research, in my case by me). The dictionary is, for example, of the form `[Integrate, Integer, KroneckerDelta, ...]`. Readline refers to this array and know whether or not completion can be done to partial word like `Inte` or `Kroneck`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may be able to use some code like this

```
repl[prompt_: ""] := Module[{input}, Print[]; While[True,
  input = InputString[prompt]; If[input == "quit", Break[],
     Print[]; Print["Out[", ++$Line, "]= ",   
       ToExpression@input]]; Print[]]];
```

an example of a [Read-eval-print loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) function which may do what you want and can be easily customized.

An example session is as follows

```
Mathematica 10.2.0 for Microsoft Windows (32-bit)
Copyright 1988-2015 Wolfram Research, Inc.

In[1]:= repl[prompt_: ""] := Module[
       {input}, Print[]; While[True,
        input = InputString[prompt];
        If[input == "quit", Break[], Print[];
         Print["Out[", $Line++, "]= ",   
           ToExpression@input]]; Print[]]]];

In[2]:= repl["? "]

? 3 + 5

Out[3]= 8

? f[x_] := x^2;

Out[4]= Null

? f[3 + 5]

Out[5]= 64

? quit

In[6]:=
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is truly what I wanted. By the way, do I have to call `repl[]` explicitly every time I start `wolfram` command? (`$Line` variable is not available before the first `In[1]:=` prompt is displayed, so I couldn't call `repl[]` in the configuration file.)

Comment: The example session was just an example. I don't have access to Wolfram Language engine so I can't test it out for myself. There is probably a way to get `repl[]` defined and called at startup. I don't know any details. I don't think it is a problem to call `repl[]` in a config file. Also I am not sure about `$Line`. You can also use your own line counter.

Comment: By using my own line counter, now I can call `repl[]` from the config file. That's perfect. Thank you :)